# PHP: Array merge issue A - Z != a - z

Tags: php, html, arrays, range, array-merge

What's wrong with this array merge?

```
$array_az = range('a', 'z');
$array_AZ = range('A', 'Z');
$array_09 = range(0, 9);
array_merge($array_az, $array_AZ, $array_09);
print_r($array_az); // a, b, c ... z, 0, 1 ...
```

But I want something like:
    // a, b, c, ... z, A, B, C, ... Z, 0, 1 ...

How could I get this output?
Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) returns the merged result, which means you need to store it.

```
$merged_array = array_merge($array_az, $array_AZ, $array_09);
print_r($merged_array);
```

Answer (score 4):

[array_merge](https://www.php.net/array_merge) returns the resulting array. You should be saving the result

```
$merged = array_merge($array_az, $array_AZ, $array_09);
```

Answer (score 2):

`array_merge` returns a new array and does not act on an array by reference. Try the following:

```
$array_az = array_merge($array_az, $array_AZ, $array_09);
```

`$array_az` will now contain your desired result.